# How to use different sets of SCSS variables in react library based on the parent project it is imported into

Tags: reactjs, sass

Ok, so I may be going about this wrong, so bear with me. If you think the solution is going in a totally different direction, please say so.

My company has a "monolith" style application, and it's getting hard to maintain. We have begun the process of breaking everything up into various "micro" apps, both micro-services and micro-frontends. I'm currently working on the prototype for our first micro-frontend.

We're entirely a react shop, so we're taking a simple approach of just having component libraries that export the parent of their particular "page", and then just importing that page into a shell project that just contains the navbar, react-router, etc.

Anyway, the big problem with breaking this up is our SCSS variables. We have things like colors, sizes, etc all coming from a core SCSS variables file. This wouldn't be such a big deal except for the fact that we have two separate frontends for our app. Basically two separate portals that share a lot of the same UI elements, with some differences, for different sets of customers. This is another reason why we're going this route, micro-frontends will make it easier to share the UI features. However, these two portals each have different color palettes and other items to distinguish them.

So, what does all of this mean? It means I have SCSS files that look like this:

```
@import '../../assets/css/variables';

.delete-text {
    color: $color-secondary;
}
```

The "$color-secondary" is a variable that comes from the imported variables file. Our two portals have separate variables files. The names are all identical, but the values are different.

So I'm sitting here staring at these SCSS files and wondering how I can make them conditionally use different sets of variables. The fact that I cannot do conditional imports is a challenge.

This is a React project. The individual libraries (aka our micro-frontends) are built with just Babel, our main projects they get imported into use Webpack. Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe an excellent use case for `css-in-js`. For example, you can use `styled-components`  to maintain a theme across the entire app while giving you the flexibility of changing it with a string. The added benefit is that you don't have to maintain any stylesheets and each component is reusable. Read more here: https://www.styled-components.com/. See simple example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lr6knqmq27

Comment: Here's another example with some theming: https://codesandbox.io/s/l2wl3866kq

Comment: The problem with this is it would require a complete re-architecting of our project's CSS. This introduces a whole lot of potential complications.

Comment: Two other solutions: 1.) Use SCSS `module` imports with `mixins` and import both classNames and utilize a `string` to determine which theme to use: https://codesandbox.io/s/81wj56r1yj (you'll have to decide on how to implement it across your components -- either via React's `context` API or `redux` state). 2.) Rewrite your SCSS variables and combine your assets.